# What is the best way to generate a <select> from this array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array
  (
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 6
        [Name] => Primary Sport
        [Values] => Array
            (
                [ClientIndexValue] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 23
                                [Name] => Boxing
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 24
                                [Name] => Cycling
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 25
                                [Name] => Running
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 46
        [Name] => Primary Fitness Goal
        [Values] => Array
            (
                [ClientIndexValue] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 512
                                [Name] => Competition
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 513
                                [Name] => Flexibility
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 514
                                [Name] => Having Fun
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 61
        [Name] => Military
        [Values] => Array
            (
                [ClientIndexValue] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 550
                                [Name] => Marines
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 551
                                [Name] => Air Force
                                [Active] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is create a `<select>` for each array where the `<option>` tags are the values of the last of the arrays using PHP so the result would be this:

```
<label>Primary Sport</label>
<select name="6" id="6">
<option value="23">Boxing</option>
<option value="24">Cycling</option>
<option value="25">Running</option>
</select>

<label>Primary Fitness Goal</label>
<select name="46" id="46">
<option value="512">Competition</option>
<option value="513">Flexibility</option>
<option value="514">Having Fun</option>
</select>

<label>Military</label>
<select name="61" id="61">
<option value="550">Marines</option>
<option value="551">Air Force</option>
</select>
```

I understand that a foreach loop is an option here but I'm having difficulty getting my head around exactly how to structure the foreach loop for so many dimensions of the array. All the examples I've found are structured like this:

```
foreach( $first_array as $key => $value) {
  foreach( $second_array    as $second ){
      if ($second['menu_url'] == $key) {
          echo "Hi";
       }
      }
     }
```

How do I access the third array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question wasn't too far off.

```
foreach ($array as $entry) {
  echo $entry['Name'];

  foreach ($entry['Values']['ClientIndexValue'] as $option) {
    echo $option['Name'];
  }
}
```

Is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Learning is the detection of patterns and most tutorials are *terrible* at visualizing patterns. I *always* use `$k1 => $v1` and increment the integers on the variables. If you have an array at a fourth level just hit the Enter key on the `foreach ($v2 as $k3 => $v3)` and replicate what is above it.

```
<?php
foreach ($array_first as $k1 => $v1)
{
 if (is_array($v1))
 {
  foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2)
  {
   if (is_array($v2))
   {
    foreach ($v2 as $k3 => $v3)
    {
     //Presuming no fourth level array:
     echo '<option>---Third Level</option>';
    }
   }
   else {echo '<option>--Second Level</option>';}//not array
  }
 }
 else {echo '<option>-First Level</option>';}//not array
}
?>
```

Don't forget to use [break](http://php.net/break) in other instances where you're looking for particular data.